# How to draw a string without padding

Tags: c#, .net, gdi, ownerdrawn

I am using the `GraphicsPath.AddString()` function, but it draws the text with a little space around the text. Any idea how to draw the string without that padding, only the paths of the text?

My code is like this:

```
GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath();

gp.AddString(text, font.FontFamily, (int)font.Style, font.Size,
    boundsRectangle, format);

g.DrawPath(pen, gp);
```

Comment: What have you set in the FormatFlags in the StringFormat parameter?

Comment: thanks plinth for the reply, the StringFromat is    _format = StringFormat.GenericDefault; is there some thing can solve the problem in the flags?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118686/measurestring-pads-the-text-on-the-left-and-the-right

Comment: Could you post a snapshot? How large is the space?

Answer (score 4):

What is happening is the under the hood it is probably using Graphics.MeasureString(), from the documentation :

> GDI+ adds a small amount (1/6 em) to each end of every string displayed. This 1/6 em allows >for glyphs with overhanging ends (such as italic 'f'), and also gives GDI+ a small amount >of leeway to help with grid fitting expansion.
>
> The default action of DrawString will work against you in displaying adjacent runs:
>
> Firstly the default StringFormat adds an extra 1/6 em at each end of each output;
> Secondly, when grid fitted widths are less than designed, the string is allowed to contract
> by up to an em.
> To avoid these problems:
>
> Always pass MeasureString and DrawString a StringFormat based on the typographic >StringFormat (GenericTypographic).
> Set the Graphics TextRenderingHint to TextRenderingHintAntiAlias. This rendering method >uses anti-aliasing and sub-pixel glyph positioning to avoid the need for grid-fitting, and >is thus inherently resolution independent.

So it looks like you should be able to fix this using the correct StringFormat.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work.  It removes the horizontal padding, but the vertical padding is still there.