# C# single font character size?

Tags: c#, fonts, drawstring

*This is not about the size of a string.*

I specify a font for drawing strings. And now I need the **exact** width of 1 character in pixels. I only allow fonts that have static char-width (W and i have the same width when drawn). If I use "Consolas" with size of 10 I get an estimated width of `7.75f`. Can I retrieve this information directly somehow ?

I don't need this information while drawing but when I want to set cursor position etc. So I don't know what text is beneath cursor.

**Edit:** MeasureString gives me 11.99653 as char width. Dunno why. But I can't use this value. I estimated 7.75f and it's pretty exact. I'll get in trouble if I want to change font size.

Comment: The inaccuracy of `MeasureString` is discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118686/measurestring-pads-the-text-on-the-left-and-the-right), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811916/measurestring-and-drawstring-difference) and [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0d991394-4911-42b8-8cb5-7cd3c745c87b/graphicsmeasurestring-is-not-accurate).

Comment: You cannot make this work, pretty fundamental about the way Windows renders text.  It alters the letter shape, stretching it as necessary to make the stems in a letter coincide with the pixel grid.  This produces highly readable text but highly unpredictable widths.  True resolution independent text rendering was never accurate enough in GDI+.  And tried again in WPF and universally panned for lousy readability.  Fixed in .NET 4.0 by adding the distinction between Display and Ideal rendering modes.  Only ever measure complete strings, never individual letters.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`MeasureString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xe5hazb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
g.MeasureString("A", font, 10, StringFormat.GenericTypographic);
```

where `font` is an instance of the [`Font`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.font%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class.

Comment: This isn't working for me. I get a value I can't use. See my edit.

Comment: @mini-me, either you defined `font` different than your specifications, or the `7.75f` isn't right. This is an exact measurement of a single character with the `font` provided by the operating system.

Comment: @mini-me, based on the comment by ORMapper, I've edited my answer.

Comment: Ok, now we getting closer. But this value is a little too low now. Is there no other way to calc this ?

Comment: @mini-me, not that I know of.